# Why are cllient components not working - NextJS 13.3.0 experimental features

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, beta

As I understand the beta docs, I need to use `"use client"` at top of my client component to be defined as one, and I can use it inside *server components*, *leaves* or *layouts*.

With that so, here's my code.

**ClientComponent.js**

```
"use client";

export default function ClientComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>This is a client component!</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**ServerComponent.js**

```
import ClientComponent from "./ClientComponent"

export default function ServerComponent() 
{

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is a server component!</h1>
            <ClientComponent/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Page.js** (Leaf)

```
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

import ServerComponent from './ServerComponent';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main styles={inter.className}>
      <ServerComponent/>
    </main>
  )
}
```

But I get this error:

> Unhandled Runtime Error
>
> SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON
>
> Call Stack JSON.parse
>
> React
>
> parseModel
>
> node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js
> (33:0)
>
> resolveModule
>
> node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js
> (749:0)
>
> processFullRow
>
> node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js
> (825:0)
>
> processBinaryChunk
>
> node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js
> (869:0)
>
> progress
>
> node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js
> (1476:0)

Even if I put directly the *client component* inside `<main>` in the leaf, it appears the same error. I do not understand what's happening as I'd followed the docs. Can someone help?

**EDIT:** This only happen when client components are added anywhere to the code.

**EDIT 2:** Look at this repo I made on GitHub, it contains a project with a nearly identical code that causes the same issue https://github.com/Benevos/nextjs-error

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error. The snippets you gave works fine.

Comment: May this be a problem with my installation of Next? As I see,  the compiler is reading "use client" as a JSON. I don't know if that's how supposed to be

Comment: Im having the same error, could you fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found solution here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/47704#issuecomment-1500914372

Just use arrow functions

Change

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main styles={inter.className}>
      <ServerComponent/>
    </main>
  )
}
```

to

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <main styles={inter.className}>
      <ServerComponent/>
    </main>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: This solved it, at least on Windows 11. Thank you

Comment: It worked, but I also had to change every other component to arrow functions

Comment: I gived up, and used stable version, but I think I can try the new way

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the application that works in the first versions does not work in this version. It does not update the client pages according to the solution above. It is necessary to restart the server every time.